# Pinot data query in Trino

Tags: docker, trino, apache-pinot

`I am running pinot in my local machine by downloading the binary and following steps mentioned in the official documentation:

```
https://docs.pinot.apache.org/basics/getting-started/running-pinot-locally
```

The ports for pinot-controller is 9000, pinot-broker is 8099, and pinot-server is 8098.
All of which can be seen on the UI, which is accessible with localhost:9000 (When we see in the UI, it says the host is my system IPv4 address).

Now I am running trino in my local machine using a docker-compose file, which has a file called pinot.properties having:

```
connector.name=pinot
pinot.controller-urls=host.docker.internal:9000
```

Now I run trino in my local machine docker container.

The issue starts when I start to query. For example, when I run the following trino queries:

```
SHOW CATALOGS;
USE pinot.default;
SHOW TABLES;
DESCRIBE table1;
```

Above queries are running fine.

Whereas for the following queries, I am getting some unexpected error:

```
SELECT * from table1;
SELECT count(*) from table1;
```

Error received is:
Query 20231123_112801_00010_8pc7r failed: Server refused connection:

`http://<local-machine-ip>:8099/debug/routingTable/table1`

When I try to access the URL in my browser directly, I can see a JSON response which is not an error.

I have tried changing the "pinot.controller-urls" in my pinot.properties file for the trino docker container to the following:

```
1. localhost
2. 127.0.0.1
3. <local-machine-ip>
```

Along with the combination of all 3 ports i.e. (pinot-controller is 9000, pinot-broker is 8099, and pinot-server is 8098).

But in those cases, trino logs suggest that it is unable to find the hostname or service.
`

Comment: 1) are you running on Windows? 2) have you tried `host.docker.internal:8098`? 3) can you share your setup in some way?

Comment: Hi @GuruStron 1 -> I am running on Macbook 
2 -> I tried with 8098 there error is Query 20231124_101949_00002_da43f failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Total timeout 300000 ms elapsed

Comment: Hi @GuruStron can you please respond